# How to solve these simultaneous equations?

Tags: systems-of-equations, calculus-of-variations, lagrange-multiplier

I'm doing questions from this page: http://tartarus.org/gareth/maths/tripos/IB/Variational_Principles.pdf and I'm doing **Question 2013 1/I/6A**

The question asks to find the cylindrical cup of least mass, where the base has density $k\rho$ and the curved side has density $\rho$. I've called the radius of the base $r$, and the height of the cup $h$.

The goal is to find $r$ and $h$ in terms of $V, k, \rho, \pi$

I've used Lagrange multipliers to get the three equations:

$(1) \space 3k\rho r^2 + 2h - \lambda h = 0$

$(2) \space 2\rho r - \lambda r^2 = 0$

$(3) \space V = \pi r^2 h$

I get the answers $r = 2\rho /\lambda$ and $\lambda = \frac{2\pi^2 h \rho^2}{V}$
But then when I put those values into $(1)$, I get a quartic that I don't know how to solve. This question is supposed to be short, so it shouldn't involve doing any complicated solving of quartic equations. Maybe there's a factorisation, but I can't see it.

Can somebody help?

Thanks

Comment: Please show us the quartic equation you get upon substitution in (1).  Clarify which variables are known quantities, so that your Question will be more self-contained.

Comment: Yes that's right. Thanks